# Unable to modify a function to stick to one working proxy

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, proxy, multiprocessing

I've written a script in Python making use of proxies along with multiprocessing while sending requests to some links in order to parse the product name from there. My current attempt does the job erroneously but it slows down the process by trying with three new proxies in each call irrespective of the running proxy is good or bad.

As I've used multiprocessing, as in `multiprocessing.dummy` within the script, I wish to modify `parse_product_info()` function in such a way so that even when a proxy is identified as bad, it won't make multiple calls to `process_proxy()` function to generate three new proxies. To be clearer - with my current attempt whether a running proxy is good or bad, I can see that when the links are made to use within `parse_product_info(link)`, three new proxies come into play in each call as I've used `3` within `Pool()`.

I've tried with:

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

linklist = [
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO', 
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKOPWA', 
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TH42HWE', 
    'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKNREM', 
]

def process_proxy():
    global proxyVault
    if len(proxyVault)!=0:
        random.shuffle(proxyVault)
        proxy_url = proxyVault.pop()
        proxy = {'https': f'http://{proxy_url}'}
    else:
        proxy = None
    return proxy


def parse_product_info(link):
    global proxy
    try:
        if not proxy:raise #if proxy variable doesn't contain any proxy yet, it goes to the exception block to get one as long as the proxy list is not empty
        print("proxy to be used:",proxy)
        res = requests.get(link,proxies=proxy,timeout=5)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html5lib")
        try:
            product_name = soup.select_one("#productTitle").get_text(strip=True)
        except Exception: product_name = ""
        print(link,product_name)

    except Exception:
        proxy = process_proxy()
        if proxy!=None:
            return parse_product_info(link)
        else:
            pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    proxyVault = ['103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632', '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128', '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312', '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251', '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080', '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243']
    pool = Pool(3)
    pool.map(parse_product_info,linklist)
```

How can I modify `parse_product_info()` function in such a way so that it will stick to one proxy if it is a working one?

Comment: Note that ``multiprocessing.dummy`` does *not* use multiple processes, just Threads. Real multiprocessing behaves differently -- in specific, ``global`` data is not shared.

Comment: Could you name or suggest any such library which behaves exactly how multiprocessing should do? Forgive my ignorance @MisterMiyagi. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, I believe you could read/write `proxy` from/to a file.

Comment: @robots.txt The normal ``multiprocessing`` module does use proper processes. ``multiprocessing.dummy`` just replicates the same API on top of threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you are having is a race condition — multiple processes (threads since you are using `multiprocessing.dummy`) see that `proxy` is uninitialised and try to get a new `proxy`.

You can implement a `get_proxy` function using Python's [`multiprocessing.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock):

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock

lock = Lock()

def get_proxy():
    global proxy
    try:
        # If proxy already set, then no need to wait for lock
        if proxy:
            return proxy
    except NameError:
        pass
    with lock:
        try:
            # If proxy was set when waiting for lock, then don't process another
            if proxy:
                return proxy
        except NameError:
            pass
        proxy = process_proxy()
        return proxy
    return None
```

Together with a `clear_proxy` function:

```py
def clear_proxy(non_working_proxy):
    global proxy
    if non_working_proxy is None:
        return
    with lock:
        if proxy == non_working_proxy:
            proxy = None
```

And then call them instead of `process_proxy` in the `parse_product_info` function:

```
def parse_product_info(link):
    # global proxy       # Remove this
    proxy = get_proxy()  # Add this
    try:
        ...

    except Exception:
        # proxy = process_proxy()  # Remove this
        clear_proxy(proxy)         # Add this to clear a non-working proxy
        proxy = get_proxy()        # Add this to queue up to get new proxy
        if proxy!=None:
            return parse_product_info(link)
        else:
            pass
```

## A note about `multiprocessing.dummy`

As mentioned by [MisterMiyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5349916/mistermiyagi) in a comment on the question:

> Note that `multiprocessing.dummy` does *not* use multiple processes, just Threads. Real multiprocessing behaves differently -- in specific, `global` data is not shared.

In this case, I believe you could read/write `proxy` from/to a file in the `with lock` block.

Answer (score 3):

First off, despite the use of the `multiprocessing`-module, you are using multithreading here, as `.dummy` uses threads instead of processes.

I initially thought OP would be fine with multithreading since there is no indication of heavy cpu-bound work in the example, but since we now know OP really might want to use multiprocessing, I also provide a multiprocessing solution.

OP's example needs a rework concerning the synchronization for the whole proxy-handling. I boiled the example down a bit by "mocking" the request part and dropping the soupy part, as it's not critical to the problem.

---

### Multiprocessing

This solution works with the use of [`multiprocessing.Value`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Value) as a shared counter for indexing into the proxy-list. In case a worker hits a timeout, it increases the shared index. The shared counter and the proxy-list are registered once at (worker-)process start-up with help of `Pool's` `initializer`-parameter.

It's important to use locks for any non-atomic operations on non-static shared resources. `multiprocessing.Value` has by default a [`multiprocessing.RLock`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.RLock) attached we can use.

```
import time
import random
import logging
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, get_logger, log_to_stderr


def request_get(link, proxies, timeout):
    """Dummy request.get()"""
    res = random.choices(["Result", "Timeout"], [0.5, 0.5])
    if res[0] == "Result":
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0, timeout))
        return f"{res[0]} from {link}"
    else:
        time.sleep(timeout)
        raise TimeoutError


def parse_product_info(link):
    global proxy_list, proxy_index    
    while True:
        with proxy_index.get_lock():
            idx = proxy_index.value
        try:
            proxy = {'https': proxy_list[idx]}
        except IndexError:
            # get_logger().info(f"No proxies left.")
            return    
        try:
            # get_logger().info(f"attempt using: {proxy}")
            res = request_get(link, proxies=proxy, timeout=5)
        except TimeoutError:
            # get_logger().info(f"timeout with: {proxy}")
            with proxy_index.get_lock():
                # check with lock held if index is still the same
                if idx == proxy_index.value:
                    proxy_index.value += 1
                    # get_logger().info(f"incremented index: {proxy_index.value}")
        else:
            # get_logger().info(f"processing: {res}")
            return    


def _init_globals(proxy_list, proxy_index):
    globals().update(
        {'proxy_list': proxy_list, 'proxy_index': proxy_index}
    )
```

Main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    log_to_stderr(logging.INFO)

    links = [
        'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO',
        'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKOPWA',
        'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TH42HWE',
        'https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKNREM',
    ]

    proxies = [
        '103.110.37.244:36022', '180.254.218.229:8080', '110.74.197.207:50632',
        '1.20.101.95:49001', '200.10.193.90:8080', '173.164.26.117:3128',
        '103.228.118.66:43002', '178.128.231.201:3128', '1.2.169.54:55312',
        '181.52.85.249:31487', '97.64.135.4:8080', '190.96.214.123:53251',
        '52.144.107.142:31923', '45.5.224.145:52035', '89.218.22.178:8080',
        '192.241.143.186:80', '113.53.29.218:38310', '36.78.131.182:39243'
    ]
    proxies = [f"http://{proxy}" for proxy in proxies]
    proxy_index = Value('i', 0)

    with Pool(
            processes=3,
            initializer=_init_globals,
            initargs=(proxies, proxy_index)
    ) as pool:

        pool.map(parse_product_info, links)
```

Example Output:

```
[INFO/MainProcess] allocating a new mmap of length 4096
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] child process calling self.run()
...
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKOPWA
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] timeout with: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] incremented index: 1
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] attempt using: {'https': 'http://180.254.218.229:8080'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] timeout with: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] attempt using: {'https': 'http://180.254.218.229:8080'}
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TH42HWE
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKNREM
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-1] processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] process shutting down
[INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] process shutting down
...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

### Multithreading

The proposal below synchronizes proxy-handling with help of a [`threading.Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) (also available wrapped as `multiprocessing.dummy.Lock`), which is possible because `multiprocessing.dummy` uses threads only.

Nota that `multiprocessing.Lock` (not from `.dummy`) in comparison is a heavy (relatively slow) IPC-Lock which will make an impact on overall performance depending on how often you synchronize.

**Edit:**

The multithreading solution has been refactored from an earlier draft to pick up the design from the multiprocessing solution above. `parse_product_info()` is now almost identical for multithreading / multiprocessing.

```
import time
import random
import logging
from itertools import repeat
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool, Lock
get_logger = logging.getLogger


def request_get(link, proxies, timeout):
    ... # same as in multiprocessing solution above


def parse_product_info(link):
    global proxies, proxy_index
    while True:
        with proxy_lock:
            idx_proxy = proxy_index
        try:
            proxy = {'https': proxies[idx_proxy]}
        except IndexError:
            # get_logger().info(f"No proxies left.")
            return
        try:
            # get_logger().info(f"attempt using: {proxy}")
            res = request_get(link, proxies=proxy, timeout=5)
        except TimeoutError:
            # get_logger().info(f"timeout with: {proxy}")
            with proxy_lock:
                if idx_proxy == proxy_index:
                    proxy_index += 1
                    # get_logger().info(f"incremented index:{proxy_index}")
        else:
            # get_logger().info(f"processing: {res}")
            return    


def init_logging(level=logging.INFO):
    fmt = '[%(asctime)s %(threadName)s] --- %(message)s'
    logging.basicConfig(format=fmt, level=level)
    return logging.getLogger()
```

Main:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    init_logging()

    linklist = ... # same as in multiprocessing solution above    
    proxies = ... # same as in multiprocessing solution above
    proxy_index = 0
    proxy_lock = Lock()

    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        pool.map(parse_product_info, links)
```

Example Output:

```
[2019-12-18 01:40:25,799 Thread-1] --- attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:25,799 Thread-2] --- attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:25,799 Thread-3] --- attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:26,164 Thread-1] --- processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00OI0RGGO
[2019-12-18 01:40:26,164 Thread-1] --- attempt using: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:29,568 Thread-1] --- processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKNREM
[2019-12-18 01:40:30,800 Thread-2] --- timeout with: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:30,800 Thread-2] --- incremented index: 1
[2019-12-18 01:40:30,800 Thread-2] --- attempt using: {'https': 'http://180.254.218.229:8080'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:30,800 Thread-3] --- timeout with: {'https': 'http://103.110.37.244:36022'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:30,801 Thread-3] --- attempt using: {'https': 'http://180.254.218.229:8080'}
[2019-12-18 01:40:32,941 Thread-3] --- processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TH42HWE
[2019-12-18 01:40:34,677 Thread-2] --- processing: Result from https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00TPKOPWA

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Reply to OP's most recent comment:

If you wish, you can exchange the list of proxies in the `IndexError` exception-handler block once all proxies are consumed. In the code you exchange `return` for:

```
        with proxy_lock:
            proxies = new_proxies
            proxy_index = 0
        continue
```

Comment: It seems to be working in the right way. However, it's a bit heavy for my current use case.

Comment: @robots.txt What do you mean by heavy? Btw, I'm about to also post a multiprocessing solution in case you really have the need for it.

Comment: I tried with yours @Darkonaut. This is so elegantly awesome!!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it possible to use `proxies.pop()` instead of `proxies[idx_proxy]` keeping your existing logic intact that you have shown in your `Multithreading` approach @Darkonaut? The reason I wish to go for `proxies.pop()` is because I will (for future usage) keep track of the proxylist to be sure whether the list has become empty so that I can update the list while the script is running. In fact, ***[this](https://filebin.net/txu7q9wll87tdus6)*** is how I usually do. Thanks

Comment: @robots.txt So you don't have a limited number of proxies from the start? You don't need to switch to `.pop()` to update your list when you're out of proxies. You can update the proxy-list like you wish in the exeption-handler block where you got the `IndexError` because you hit the end of the list. See the last edit for code.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. Thanks.